# Regex for finding Instagram-style hashtag in string - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I'm struggling to build a regex in Ruby to be able to wrap hashtags from a string in some HTML.

Here's what I have so far:

```
description.gsub!(/#\w+/, '[#\1]')
```

This should be a regex to pick up hashtags that contain letters, numbers and underscores - and be split on anything other than these, such as a space or HTML tag.

This should input:

```
hello there #obiwan
```

and output:

```
hello there [#obiwan]
```

But currently it outputs:

```
hello there [#]
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: There is no capture group, I think it should be `#(\w+)` and `'[#\\1]'` or `/#\w+/` and `'[\\0]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer to a capture group, you can use `\\1` but in the current pattern there is no group.

You can add a capture group in the pattern:

```
description.gsub(/#(\w+)/, '#[\\1]')
```

Or use the full match in the replacement:

```
description.gsub(/#\w+/, '[\\0]')
```

Comment: This works great! If I wanted to tweak this to use for @usernames, that can also contain a period - would this be an ideal use? `gsub!(/@([\w.]+)/, "[\\0]"`

Comment: Similarly, can I use a combination of \A and \s to ensure there's a space or the start of the string before the regex? So that matches such as an email address won't be captured, but a hashtag at the start of the string will be replaced.

Comment: @Kobius You can use `@[\w.]+` but it will also match `@...` so if there should only be a dot between word characters use `@\w+(?:\.\w+)*` https://regex101.com/r/scpIWp/1 If you want to match either a hashtag or @ you could also use `\B[@#]\w+(?:\.\w+)*` https://regex101.com/r/2SJEjQ/1